# What are the differences between "blithe" and "beatific", if any?

Tags: meaning, difference, usage, vocabulary

[The Free Dictionary](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/) defines the words in question as follows:

- > blithe (blaɪð, blaɪθ)
  >
  > Definition:
  >
  > 1. lighthearted in disposition; cheerful.
  > 2. heedless: a blithe disregard for someone's feelings.
- > beatific (bē′ə-tĭf′ĭk)
  >
  > 1. displaying great happiness, calmness, etc
  >    Example: a beatific smile.
  > 2. (Theology) of, conferring, or relating to a state of celestial happiness

I've notice that one of *blithe*'s definitions ("lighthearted in disposition; cheerful") is similar to the first definition of "beatific". I picked up on this similarity after doing some research on *beatific*.
How does definition 1 of 'blithe' relate to definition 1 of 'beatific'?
If they don't, how do these definition entries differ?

I would gladly appreciate it if anyone would take time out of their busy schedule to shed some light on this dichotomy.

Comment: Personally, I think that 'beatific' is much stronger than 'blithe', and the latter has potential nuanced usages not available to the former. They are not really synonymous, any more than 'sad' and 'devastated' are.

Comment: I agree with Michael Harvey, but would add that neither are really in common use today (in UK English at least). I've never heard or used "beatific" in conversation, and have only occasionally used "blithe" in conversation ("I was blithely going about my business when...").

Comment: Visionaries vastly prefer beatific experiences to blithe ones. Careless drivers show blithe rather than beatific disregard for others.

Comment: @RonaldSole I have met a few people whose state I could describe as beatific. Some were that way because of drugs, some because of religion, and with one fellow it seemed he was born that way.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey That I should be so lucky, and that after 10 years as a monk!

Comment: I hear "blithely" from time to time, but rarely "blithe", unless it be a reference to Noel Coward's play Blithe Spirit (1941), whose title he nicked from Shelley's poem To A Skylark (1820), or to Shakespeare's song “Sigh no more, ladies..." from Much Ado (1612): "Men were deceivers ever...|Then sigh not so, but let them go,|And be you **blithe** and bonny..." As well as its druggy and religious associations (explored in depth above!), "A **beatific** look on his face" is sometimes used of one who is guilty but contrives to look innocent: "He looked as if butter wouldn't melt in his mouth".

Comment: @RonaldSole - I knew someone, an ordained priest (equivalent) in the Salvation Army, who told me that she distrusted some of her fellows who claimed to have the 'gift of the Holy Spirit'. She said there was a competitiveness and, sometimes, smugness about them that she disliked. 'Being blissed out' and 'holier than thou' she called it.

Comment: @RonaldSole - she said that there was plenty of time 'later' for all that bliss business. She felt that she should spend her time here on Earth doing the Lord's work, which in her case involved social work in the most deprived areas of inner cities. As an atheist, I think she was one of the finest Christians I have ever met.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey When judgement day comes (I have my own doubts) there are going to be a lot of surprises!